# Como Modern OpenGL funciona?

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

Eu já estudei OpenGL, e agora eu tava lendo o Modern OpenGL, eu tava vendo uns vídeos no YouTube e uns tutoriais na internet e eu escrevi esse código:

```
import pyglet, numpy, ctypes
from OpenGL.GL import *
import OpenGL.GL.shaders as shader

a = pyglet.window.Window()

t = [-.5,-.5,0,.5,-.5,0,.5,.5,0]
t = numpy.array(t, dtype=numpy.float32)

v = """
void main(){
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
"""

f = """
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1,1,1,1);
}
"""

s = shader.compileProgram(shader.compileShader(v,GL_VERTEX_SHADER),shader.compileShader(f,GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER))

VBO = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, len(t), t, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glUseProgram(s)

@a.event
def on_draw():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    glBindVertexArray(0)
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3)

def SRO(dt):
    on_draw()

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(SRO, 1/30)

pyglet.app.run()
```

Era para aparecer um triangulo Branco, mas a janela só abre e fica uma tela preta, eu pesquisei alguns códigos, adicionei um `glVertexAttribPointer` que não funcionou(ou pelo menos bugou bastante o código) e um `glBindVertexArray` que também não fez muita diferença. Alguém aí sabe onde eu estou errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você estudou OpenGL versão 3.2 (ou superior) ou alguma versão anterior a essa? se usou a função glVertex é porque estava na versão abaixo da 3.2, que é totalemente diferente de como se faz hoje.

Seu código está incompleto, vc usou `glBufferData`, que é uma função que faz o upload dos bytes da CPU para GPU, em seguida você ainda precisa dizer como esses bytes estão organizados com `glVertexAttribPointer`.

Você também deveria explicitamente alocar um VAO, mas para o seu triangulo aparecer sozinho na tela não é obrigatório usar o VAO.

Na sua função `on_draw` você chama o `glBindVertexArray` que linka com o VAO padrão e em seguida faz a chamada da função de desenho, essa parte tá certa, se vc alocasse o VAO explicitamente vc teria que dizer qual é o handler do VAO.

OpenGL programável não é algo tão trivial para começar escrevendo códigos aleatórios e verificar o que acontence na execução. Recomendo que leia todo o capítulo de Getting Started do learnopengl (https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/OpenGL), antes de sair escrevendo código OpenGL.

obs: não utilize a função ftransform (está no seu vertex shader), a menos que saiba o que está fazendo.

Mais obs: A maioria dos exemplos e cursos/tutoriais que você vai encontrar será em C++, todos que eu conheço de alta qualidade são em C++. Nada te impede de escrever seu código em python, mas se quer realmente aprender OpenGL vai ter que aprender C/C++ também.